# VB Script help! Expected... errors on checking syntax or saving

Tags: vbscript, qtp

I created a fairly simple function, but I must have overlooked something because I get 3 errors on saving:

1. Expected ')'
2. Expected end of statement
3. Expected End Sub or End Function or End Property

Here is the code:

```
Function ReportCheck(sParent, sReport, sTitle)

        oParentWindow = "My_Reports," & sParent

        BuildAndRunObject "My_Reports" , sReport,"LINK", "CLICK","","", "ABORT","","","","" 
        BuildAndRunObject oParentWindow ,sTitle,"WEBELEMENT", "EXIST","","", "","","","","" 
        'BuildAndRunObject oParentWindow ,"select","WEBELEMENT", "SELECT","2009 - 2013","SELECT_VALUE", "ABORT","","","","" 
        BuildAndRunObject oParentWindow ,"Create","WEBBUTTON", "CLICK","","", "ABORT","","","",""   
        Wait(20)
            If BuildAndReportObject(oParentWindow, "Checkmark", "WEBELEMENT","VERIFY PROPERTY VALUE".TRUE. "VISIBLE","","","","","")  and BuildAndReportObject(oParentWindow, "Report_Ready", "WEBELEMENT","VERIFY PROPERTY VALUE". TRUE. "VISIBLE","","","","","") Then
                Reporter.ReportEvent micPass, "Credit Summary", "Report Generated Successfully"
            Else
                Reporter.ReportEvent micFail, sTitle, "Report Failed to Generate"
            End if
End Function
```

The first error is for the IF line.
The second error is for the Else.  And the last is for the End If line.

What did I miss?  I appreciate the second look.  I am the only one at my company that uses VB Script so I don't have anyone to take a look...

Thanks,

Jamie

Answer (score 2):

It seems you try to concatenate strings with the `.` - that is valid in PHP e.g., VBS uses `&` (take care that spaces are required around the `&`).

Comment: Not sure what you are referring to with the concatenate.  The only place I concatenate is setting the oParentWindow. The BuildAndRunObject is a function and the parameters are what follows.

Comment: What do you want to achieve with
`"VERIFY PROPERTY VALUE".TRUE. "VISIBLE"`? The dot has no valid meaning here.

Answer (score 0):

While I am not sure exactly what the issue was...

I retyped the above code in.  I think QTP did not like something in my copy/paste and maybe there was a space or character I could not see that caused an issue.  When I retyped the code - same as it appears above - then deleted the previous code, it passed a syntax check.  More importantly - it ran without issue.

So, when in doubt, retype code line by line checking syntax as you go.  Lesson learned.

Thanks to all that took the time to read and to KekuSemau for responding!

Jamie